# How to bind control property?

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I am using the convention-based binding from Caliburn.Micro, but I have a small issue:

How do I set the property that my binding should bind to? If I create a control with `x:Name="SomeProperty"`, how do I choose if the value of `SomeProperty` should be binded to the `Value` Property of my control, the `OnClick` Event of my control or something different, like the `Content` or the `Tag` property?

Example: I have this `HyperlinkButton` that I want to bind to a specific URL, and I want to bind the `OnClick` to an event handler in my ViewModel.

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="BookDetailsViewModel_InfoLink" Content="Read more" />
```

The Content property however is not filled with `Read more` but with the value of the URL. In this example, how do I:

- Set the navigation URI to the value of the URL in my ViewModel property
- Set the content to "Read more"
- Specify an event handler in my ViewModel that will handle the click

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Are you saying you want to customise the conventions for this control so that it does what you want or you are just having trouble getting this working with or without conventions? My assumption is that you want the conventions to do this all for you

Comment: I just want it to work, I don't really care if it works with or without the conventions. Some explicit binding code is fine with me, but when I use {Binding SomeProperty} it doesn't work.

Comment: Added explanation of how to do it both convention based and explicitly. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the ConventionManager per element type in CM. The default out-of-box implemententation is applied to any element which doesn't have an explicit customisation

To add a new convention you just simply call ConventionManager.AddElementConvention

The method looks like this (from CM source)

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds an element convention.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of element.</typeparam>
/// <param name="bindableProperty">The default property for binding conventions.</param>
/// <param name="parameterProperty">The default property for action parameters.</param>
/// <param name="eventName">The default event to trigger actions.</param>
public static ElementConvention AddElementConvention<T>(DependencyProperty bindableProperty, string parameterProperty, string eventName)
{
    return AddElementConvention(new ElementConvention
    {
        ElementType = typeof(T),
        GetBindableProperty = element => bindableProperty,
        ParameterProperty = parameterProperty,
        CreateTrigger = () => new EventTrigger { EventName = eventName }
    });
}
```

As you can see, it takes a few args - you need to pass the default property for bindings, actions, and triggers e.g.

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<HyperlinkButton>(HyperlinkButton.NavigateUri, "NavigateUri", "Click");
```

(assuming the click event is called Click)

Since you aren't binding the `Content` property any more (because the convention is to now bind NavigateUri) you can just leave that as-is and it should remain 'Read more...'

So now you have a `HyperlinkButton` control which should bind by convention to the `NavigateUri`, and call the method which shares it's name when the `Click` event is triggered.

Edit:

*I might make a clarification that I don't think you can bind to **both** a method and a property on the same VM since you can't have a method and a property that share the same name, but I'm sure CM would bubble the action message up the VM hierarchy if you didn't have the appropriate method on the VM... not tried it though. To bind the actions see my other edit below*

Don't forget, you could always just use the explicit syntax for all of this!

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Read more..." NavigationURI="{Binding SomeUri}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action HyperlinkClicked($this.NavigateUri)" />
```

but it's probably better to go the convention route :)

Edit:

Might add how to get convention to grab the property value from the hyperlink -

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="SomeLink" Content="Read more..." cal:Message.Attach="HyperlinkClicked(SomeLink)" />
```

CM knows that since you set `NavigateUri` as the default action parameter, it should grab this and pass it to the method that you specified in the action binding. I'm wondering if `$this` will also work (you probably would need `$this.NavigateUri`). You can do this across controls e.g.

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" />
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="SomeLink" Content="Read more..." cal:Message.Attach="HyperlinkClicked(SomeTextBox)" />
```

The above would pass the `Text` property of the textbox to the `HyperlinkClicked` method by default.

Comment: I tried the explicit solution, and it arrives at the event handler of my viewmodel, but the argument is empty. My method looks like this:

`public void HyperlinkClicked(EventArgs args)`

Am I passing the wrong type of argument here? I couldn't figure what type of argument it should accept (how does one know these things?).

Comment: CM doesn't use `EventArgs` - it uses the type of the property. If you go into code-behind and declare a HyperlinkButton and see what type the `NavigateURI` property is (is it string maybe? or URI?) and use that as the argument type. If in doubt, set the type on the method as `object` and breakpoint it - see type the argument was passed as by CM. CM will pass null to parameters that it can't match with the supplied so it shouldn't throw an exception but it will call the method regardless. My guess is `public void HyperlinkClicked(string uri)` will work. (ok I lied, docs say its System.Uri)

Comment: Hmm, my hyperlink is binded to a string, but I get `null` even time, even when I set the parameter to be an object.

This is my XAML: `<HyperlinkButton Content="Open in web browser" NavigateUri="{Binding BookDetailsViewModel_PreviewLink}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action HyperlinkClicked($this.NavigateURI)]" />`

Comment: NavigateUri - CAPS on `URI` should be `Uri` my bad. The property resolver is case sensitive since c# is case sensitive. Like I said, you are probably better off using convention as it can help avoid this little mistakes since nothing will check this at design time. Oh yeah and just because `NavigateUri` is bound to a string, doesn't mean the property will be string - there are things called `TypeConverters` in WPF/RT/SL which which convert the passed in value to the required type, so the converter for NavigateUri parses the bound string and converts it to a `System.Uri`.

Comment: Some useful info on `TypeConverters` here in case you ever decide to write your own control or even `UserControl`... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx - can be useful for when you want to provide values to your custom controls via XAML markup

Comment: I already figured that 'URI' was a typo so I tried 'Uri' as well, didn't work. I tried your convention-based method now:

`<HyperlinkButton x:Name="BookDetailsViewModel_PreviewLink" Content="Read more..." cal:Message.Attach="HyperlinkClicked($this)" />`

This seems to work like a charm. Thanks a lot for your awesome help!

Comment: I have to wait 22 hours to give you your bounty, but you'll get it.

Comment: You're welcome - CM is awesome, just glad other people are finding out how good it is!

Comment: I recently switched from MVVMLight, I wanted to give CM a try :-) There are a lot of small things that I don't understand yet, but my general impression is pretty good!